# Read Server Variable from Angular2

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-services, siteminder

We have to use SiteMinder as SSO for my app which is developed in Angular2. SiteMinder has its own login page and returns the user details in the server variables for each request.
I have to read the server variable in Angular2 for each request and validate whether the user details exist or not.

Can you suggest how it can be implemented? I am relatively new to this Angular2 development.

Thanks and appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, if you were successful implementing this, please answer your question. i need to do same, can we have a chat, my email: theakshay.jain@gmail.com